# Disable log4j 2 programmatically (log4j2)

Tags: log4j, log4j2

In log4j 1.X I disabled the log output with the following command:

```
System.setProperty("log4j.defaultInitOverride","true");
LogManager.resetConfiguration();
LogManager.getRootLogger().addAppender(new NullAppender());
```

Is there an equivalent in log4j 2.X?

Answer (score 3):

You should try:

```
Configurator.initialize(new NullConfiguration());
```